# Parse JSON Data to UIPickerView in Swift

Tags: php, json, swift

I have a UIPickerview which represents countries and i am trying to get its data from MYSQL database but i couldnt handle the coming data from PHP file. I couldnt find any Swift solution so thats why i am here.

```
//its the default values of pickerview
var pickOption = ["one", "two", "three", "seven", "fifteen"]

func getCountries() {
    let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: "http:/domain.com/getCountriesLong.php")!
    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
    let task = session.downloadTaskWithRequest(request) {
        (
        let location, let response, let error) in

        guard let _:NSURL = location, let _:NSURLResponse = response  where error == nil else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        let urlContents = try! NSString(contentsOfURL: location!, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

        guard let _:NSString = urlContents else {
            print("error")
            return
        }

        //all result is here
        //print(urlContents)
        //string to NSData conversion
        let data = urlContents.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        do {
            //parse NSData to JSON
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: .AllowFragments)

            //pickOption = json["countryName"]
            //pickOption = json

        } catch {
            print("error serializing JSON: \(error)")
        }


    }

    task.resume()

}
```

Here is the PHP

```
$menuData = $db->get_results("SELECT countryName FROM countries ORDER BY countryName ASC");

echo json_encode($menuData);
```

How can i use coming data as value of my UIPickerView ?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution. instead of using pickOption = json["countryName"] i have  declared new array. Here it is;

```
var arr = [String]()

    for name in json as! [AnyObject] {
         if let country = name["countryName"] as? String {
              arr.append(country)
         }
    }

self.pickOption = arr
```